# no fermentation

Tags: fermentation, cider, wine

I'm attempting my first batch of hard cider. I tried re-hydrating my yeast by mixing them with Go-Ferm and warm water, but the must never started fermenting so I added more dry yeast to the batch. Did I ruin the must? What can I expect to happen and what is the possible causes for it to never having started fermenting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the yeast proofed when hydrating it should be fine.

More detail of your must would help. If you used bottled Apple juice it may have a yeast inhibiting preservative.

Update: if you're sure there are no preservatives, something else is inhibiting the yeast growth.

- Yeast health, it may be dead. Repitch New yeast (check expiration date). Make sure proof water doesn't exceed 90°F. Allow yeast to get to room temp, after removing from fridge.
- To cold of fermentation temp. Bring it up to 70°F

Comment: I used apple cider with no additives and no preservatives. It's a 4 gallon must with 4# of sugar added. The yeast never "proofed," that is, it didn't respond to the Go-Ferm mixture as expected. There was an obvious separation of the Go-Ferm and yeast, but nothing more.

Comment: Go-Ferm is just nutrients. I always add just a little corn sugar after hydrating to proof the yeast.